# What does the red background on an item mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the latest update, you can now use gyms like stops and get items. So far, every time I have done so there has always been one item that has a red background and number.

[image: scree]

Is this a bonus item since I am part of red team? Is there any special meaning to it at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on my observations, your theory appears to be correct. Spinning a disc that is on a gym that your team controls will give you an extra item. That item will be indicated by the colored background that matches your team's color.

For reference, I am on Team Mystic. When spinning the disc at Valor and Instinct gyms, I did not receive a "special" item, but I have at the Mystic-controlled gyms I've spun.

[image: Valor spin]

[image: instinct spin]

[image: mystic spin]

This is also being mentioned in other places, such as [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6iw16h/put_pokemon_in_gym_before_spinning_team_bonus/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_list):

> To confirm my suspicions, the team bonus items are highlighted with team color, correct?
>
> It seems so, yes. My team bonus was highlighted red, and I'm Valor.
>
> Flavor thing: as a Mystic player, my team bonus text and background on the bonus item are blue. Can Instinct and Valor confirm their text/background colors on bonus items?
>
> yes instinct here, yellow.
>
> Valor, the bonus item text is red.

Comment: I just love that one of the gyms is "Lady Liberty with a Burrito"

Comment: I'm Mystic, I just got 5 items from a gym-stop, 1 was blue highlighted one was yellow highlighted. pls explain

Comment: @KevinL this happened to me as well, but only to one of them 5 gyms I occupied at the time. The gym it happened on was the only gym I had a bronze badge for, so I assume it's for that.

Comment: The yellow background (when you aren't team yellow) is definitely due to having a bronze gym badge. You get two with a silver gym badge. Not sure if the shade of yellow is different from the yellow's team yellow. Poor choice of colors, for sure.