# Does the level of a gym's badge affect the gameplay?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since the last update you can now obtain a badge for a specific gym when you spin its photo disc. It is then possible to level it up by defending it, feeding the Pokemons from your team with berries or attacking it if another team is controlling it. Leveling the badges up apparently awards you with a new badge rarity, going from Bronze to Gold, as you can see from the picture below.

[image]

Does the rarity of a badge affect the gym it's linked to? For instance, can you get additional loots, or will your own Pokemon's motivation decrease more slowly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Leveling the Gym badge does have an affect on the game play.  According to [Niantic's post](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/raids):

> You can earn the opportunity to receive bonus items and increased rewards from Gyms by raising the level of your Gym Badge.

Having a higher Gym Badge level will yield more rewards and [bonus items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311683/what-does-the-red-background-on-an-item-mean) from Gyms.  At the moment, this appears to be the only thing that the Gym Badges do that I can find.

Comment: Interesting! What do you mean by "rewards" there, just to be sure? Do you get more coins for defending your gym, or does the rarity of the items you get for spinning the photo disc increases?

Comment: @Isuka definitely from the spinning disc as pointed out in the linked question in my answer. I don't think the coins are impacted in any way for the badge.  It looks like the coins are based [solely off time](https://www.primagames.com/games/pokemon-go/tips/pokemon-go-how-collect-coins) (1 hour grants 1 coin per pokemon in a gym up to 100 coins a day).  It also looks like the pokemon must be defeated before you can collect coins.

Answer (score 8):

My observation is that:

- a bronze gym badge grants you +1 bonus items
- a silver gym badge grants you +2 bonus items
- a gold gym badge grants you +3 bonus items

In addition, you get bonuses if if your team controls the gym:

- If your team controls the gym and you *do not* have a gold gym badge, you get +1 bonus items.
- If your team controls the gym and you *do* have a gold gym badge, then you get +2 bonus items (for a total of +5 bonus items, including the gold gym badge bonus).

Comment: And each bonus is multiplied by 5 on the ene of your 7 day streak.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to receiving bonus items you also get more XP for spinning:

Enemy gym:

- badgeless: 25 XP
- bronze: 50 XP
- silver: 75 XP
- gold: 100 XP

Friendly gym:

- badgeless: 31 XP
- bronze: 63 XP
- silver: 94 XP
- gold: 125 XP

Answer (score 1):

It also seems to add to your XP reward. I currently get 94 XP just for flipping my home stop (which is silver, halfway to gold, est. 16.000 badge XP).

Answer (score -1):

My observation is gold gyms that hold exraids give me an advantage for catching Mewtwo.