# How does the gym's badge level system works?

Tags: pokemon-go

Spinning the photo disc of a gym now awards you the gyms corresponding badge. It is then possible to increase your badge level by executing some specific actions, such as feeding the Pokemon of your team with berries, defending your gym or attacking an opponent gym. But, as there is no experience amount displayed on the badge, it's hard to determine how many points are needed to level up a badge, or how many points are awarded for executing a specific action.

How many points (or actions) are needed to get a new specific badge level? Do some actions award you with more points than the others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the level of a gym's badge affects the gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311715/does-the-level-of-a-gyms-badge-affects-the-gameplay)

Comment: @Jerry not a duplicate; this question is asking how the gym badge leveling works and the experience needed to level it.  The linked question is asking how the gym badge level affects gameplay.

Comment: @Jerry I asked two separate questions as the two questions are not linked on the concept. This one is related to how the leveling system around the new badge system is working. The other one is about what is the actual purpose of those badges in the game, and more precisely for the corresponding gym. Else it would more be a global question about badges, how they work, what is their purpose, how to evolve them... which might be too much for only one question.

Comment: Do we honestly need two different questions about the same thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We do know we'll be able to level up Gym Badges by performing the following activities: 
(thanks to the Silph Road sub-Reddit user for clarifying some of these numbers):

1. Battling at Gyms (CP of Pokemon defeated divided by 10)
2. Adding Pokémon to the Gym (+ 100 Badge XP)
3. Holding a creature at the Gym (+1 Badge XP per minute)
4. Giving Berries to Pokémon held at the Gym (+ 10 Badge XP, as well as 20 Stardust and a possibility of Candy)
5. Defeat a Raid Boss (1000 XP for the Badge)
6. Win a battle from a Pokemon defending the gym (0,01 XP * pokemon defending CP)

By performing the above activities, whether you are passive and prefer to increase Motivation as you pass a Gym, or are actively battling and holding creatures there, you can level up your Badge over time.

Badge XP needed for a gym medal is:

- Bronze: 500 XP
- Silver: 4000 XP
- Gold: 30000 XP

(So Silver is 3500 XP more needed after getting the Bronze gym badge)

Edit on 9 July: 
Found this webpage that also gives a lot of information about XP on Gym systems: [Gym Badge Experience](https://pokemongohub.net/gym-raid-update/gym-badge-experience/)

Comment: Good start to an answer - but how much experience is needed to level a badge? And how much does each action reward?

Comment: "Holding a creature at the Gym (+1 Badge XP per minute)" Does this mean you get the XP when the pokemon is returned?  Or maybe next time you spin the gym's disc it updates?

Comment: @Batophobia I believe when the pokemon is returned. But I am not too sure about that, since my team hardly has any Gyms in my area. (I am an Instinct in a town full of Mystics).

Comment: @Vemonus If I would have done that. How come their article as posted on 21 July 2017. And mine was posted on 23 June 2017, with a last edit on 9 July 2017. So plz. backup you accusation when posting it.

Comment: @Tenzin interesting, my bad, I didn't see the dates. Then in that case, I'd say they plagiarized this answer :)

Comment: @Batophobia I think the BXP is added at regular intervals, maybe hourly. I hit gold in a gym last night while my Blissey was in it, and it wasn't knocked out until late this morning.

Comment: When defeating a poke, the CP of the pokemon is divided by 100, not 10.